# Couchbase, CouchDB, or Couchbase Lite? Which is correct?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

There are three separate but similarly-named products out there:

- [Couchbase Server](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/introduction/intro.html)
- [Couchbase Lite (Mobile)](https://developer.couchbase.com/mobile)
- [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)

Despite the similar names and functions, these are all entirely separate products, each with their own particular idiosyncrasies and features.  Couchbase and Couchbase Lite are made by the same company, while CouchDB is an Apache product.

The problem is that Stack Overflow has tags for [couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase) (Couchbase Server), [couchdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchdb), and [couchbase-lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase-lite).  Users asking questions often tag `Couchbase` on CouchDB or Couchbase-Lite questions, leading to confusion and extended chats, and even answers that apply to something other than the product asked about.

[An example of such a question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692745/is-20-mb-document-size-limit-in-couchbase-inclusive-of-attachment-size?), where I saw the [couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase) tag, and upon reading the question text was completely unaware that the user was actually using Couchbase Lite - and until they confessed to it, I was chiding them for using a tool for something other than its intended purpose.  What's worse - the accepted answer actually applies to CouchDB. What a mess!  But this is hardly the first time this has happened.

I have edited the Wiki for [couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase) to clarify that it refers ONLY to Couchbase Server, but is this enough?  Should this tag be renamed to say [couchbase-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase-server)?

Comment: No! It is *CouchDB*, not *Couchdb*.

Comment: One of the parties better rename to *sofa*, no?

Comment: The tag wiki is (according to my experience) not read by many people. We have a sentence saying "The opengl tag should only be used for questions about desktop OpenGL. OpenGL ES (OpenGL for Embedded Systems) and WebGL have their own tags." in the [tag:opengl] wiki and still get several questions a day tagged with opengl and android. I would really love to have a exclusive or for tags.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - you'll have to forgive me, I've been working with Ada recently, which as you probably know is case-insensitive ;)

Comment: Couchbase-server makes sense to me. We could also change CouchDB to CouchDB-appache.

Comment: This issue is *so confusing* I would recommend just ignoring the topic.  I've had large clients dismiss couchbase (.... whatever) literally for this reason: nobody knows what it is.  It's utterly inconceivable folks at the executive level will it through such an explanation, and they don't.  Here on SO you should just cram the whole thing under "couch" or something.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkxvHiM3CBk

Comment: @Fattie - why would folks “at the executive level” have any need to know any technology at the implementation level of software?

Comment: hey Mayer - I meant: folks who decide "should we use couch(whatever) or should we use Firebase?" and then have to pay for one or the other.  Everyone just uses Firebase because nobody can figure out WTH couch(something?) is.

Comment: couch (something - even I don't know) is an incredible product ("GE use it to run trains, for God's sake"), but the name/products/whatever confusion has killed it off, sadly.

Comment: I guess I'm not in the habit of allowing non-technical people to make judgement calls on the design/architecture of my software. That being said, it is a good product, and as far as I know, the only product that actually does what it does as well as it does.

Comment: @rene Sofa is a blog engine written as a CouchApp, and used as an example in the O'Reilly CouchDB book -- https://github.com/jchris/sofa

Comment: @slim fair enough, *Chaise longue* it will be then ...

Comment: What about hide-a-bed?

Comment: All punny seating names are already reserved for CouchDB libraries and components.